# Access Rich Text fields

Tags: domino-appdev-pack

I need to access a rich text field inside a document, however, if I read the documents with the correct field selected, I don't receive the value of the field in the database response. How can I retrieve the data of a rich text field?

Answer (score 1):

Rich text fields are not yet supported.  Some very basic RT support is coming in 1.0.4 of the appdev pack, but I don't think you'll be able to use it yet as you would like.

Comment: do you know when the version 1.0.4 is being planned to be released?

Comment: It has been released this week!

Answer (score 0):

Our current workaround:

Convert the RTField to HTML using the rt.convertToTHML() method, save it into another field via an agent and process the HTML. Works fine for read only, embedded pictures need a little extra work

```
            RichTextItem rt = (RichTextItem) doc.getFirstItem("body");
            String html = rt.convertToHTML(null);
            doc.replaceItemValue("bodyHTML", html);
            doc.save()
```

Comment: That looks promising, i gonna try it out