# domino AppDev Pack Retrieve RichText

Tags: lotus-domino, hcl, domino-appdev-pack

I was using domino appdev pack 1.0.4 in order to retrieve richtext content, and I used the example code that HCL provides to read rich text, which would return buffer format and write the buffer into a file.

But I use Note to open the file, it seems that the content is not like the data stored in Domino Notes.
The text appeared garbled. I was wondering if there is a way to get the same content as it shows in Domino Notes. Or is it possible to convert the file into html format?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you access the Notes document with the rich text field via a Web browser, the rich text is converted to HTML as best it can.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913691/3439282

Comment: Convert the RT to HTML via an agent. See
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315715/access-rich-text-fields/60755545#60755545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315715/access-rich-text-fields/60755545#60755545)

Answer (score 0):

So in 1.0.4 the richtext data you download using that API is the CDrecord binary data from notes.  I agree that it's not terribly useful for you in the node world unless you have a way to process it.

In 1.0.5 there will be a library where you can start to parse the CDrecord data and extract text and formatting from it. Not all rich text elements will be supported yet, it's still a work in progress.